# I can't access exposed docker container from LAN

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory, docker-machine

I've one container which is worked fine for 3 months. At the moment I can't access container from network. It's accessible on host which is docker run on. Access port is 8083.

yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  registry:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "8083:8082"
~                  



[root@gitlab ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
863891ea6e3c        docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest   "/entrypoint-artifac…"   3 months ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8083->8082/tcp   root_registry_1_7d69431cd9ce

[root@gitlab ~]# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9121          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1844/redis_exporter 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1850/prometheus     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9187          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1886/postgres_expor 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9093          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1887/alertmanager   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1866/registry       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1890/node_exporter  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9229          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1859/gitlab-workhor 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1837/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1857/puma 4.3.3.git 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1864/puma 4.3.3.git 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1837/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2754/sidekiq 5.2.7  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9236          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2111/gitaly         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      953/sshd            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1885/grafana-server 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1142/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1837/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1837/nginx: master  
tcp6       0      0 :::9094                 :::*                    LISTEN      1887/alertmanager   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9168                :::*                    LISTEN      1864/puma 4.3.3.git 
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      1627/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::8083                 :::*                    LISTEN      1613/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      953/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1142/master         
udp6       0      0 :::9094                 :::*                                1887/alertmanager
```

Comment: Anything in the container logs?

Comment: Logs seems clear to me. Also container works well and replying curl when I run host . (curl localhost:8083) @Henry

Comment: How is this docker host connected to network, is it VM or another physical server ?

Comment: It's a VM. Also gitlab working well on this host. @Sandeep

Comment: Check whether the port forwarding from VM is messed up @ErcanKoc